# Merge three json result into one json

Tags: python, json, django, rest, backend

I have these three json file:

First:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 100,
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

Second:

```
[
    {
        
        "new_id": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "date": 01/01/2023
    }
]
```

Third:

```
[
    {
        
        "new_id": 0,
        "start_date": 01/01/2024
    }
]
```

I want to merge these three json response together, the ideal result should be:

Final:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 100,
        "new_id": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "date": 01/01/2023
        "start_date": 01/01/2024

    }
]
```

I tried the method of update and update the first and second using a dict(hashmap). Is there a way to do this all together? by depending on two field "id" and "new_id"?

```
merged = {}

with open('File1.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        jsonified = json.loads(line)
        merged[jsonified['id']] = jsonified

with open('File2.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        jsonified = json.loads(line)
        merged[jsonified['id']].update(jsonified)
```

Comment: You can use `(id, new_id)` tuple as dict key, and use `None` when `new_id` is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this:

```
import json

res = {}
for file in ["1.json", "2.json", "3.json"]:
    with open(file) as f:
        res.update(json.load(f)[0])

print(res)

# {'amount': 100, 'id': 1, 'new_id': 0, 'date': '01/01/2023', 'start_date': '01/01/2024'}
```

Comment: what if I want to join not just "0"? What if I want to do like all of the 'id'?

Comment: You can nest another layer of traversal in the code, but here are two things to keep in mind.
1. what metrics are used to distinguish different data, dictionary data cannot be duplicated, meaning that different ids are stored in different dictionaries
2. how to store the overall data?, it is recommended to use JSON format or a list composed of dictionaries

Comment: Let's say if my data is having id up to 5, and new_id up to 5 as well. I want to merge everything that have same id and same new_id together. what type of syntax and code structure it may look like?

Comment: I do want to figure out this myself but it seems hard to find an example online that I can try and mimick from...

Comment: You need to add some judgment conditions with if, you can give us your example and we will discuss it based on the actual data